# Install App via Apple Configurator

Tags: ios, deployment, apple-configurator

I found that I can install IPA via Apple Configurator to my devices, without consuming the device quota of my Apple Developer account. It looks great, so what is the drawback to do so?

My plan is to deploy a single App to 50 iDevices. Is there any better way to do so?

AFAIK, If I install via Xcode with Provisioning Profile, the profile will expire & the App will become unusable, and the device itself will consume a device quota in my Apple Developer Account.

Notes:

- the App has no plan to submit to App Store
- my Apple Developer Program has no 50 extra device quotas
- I can access to the 50 devices physically (can connect via USB cables)
- won't consider jailbreak ways
- won't consider using iExplorer / iTools